# Why is this Java variable assignment illegal?

Tags: java

Here is the code

```
import java.util.*;
 class Example
 {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    final int x=127; int y=100;
    byte b;
    b=x; //Legal ?
    b=y; //Illegal 
  }
 }
```

Can you explain why `b=y` is illegal? I think `final` means no further change, is that correct?

Comment: Can you explain which lines do you expect to be legal and illegal? Otherwise it's quite hard to guess which aspect of this code it is that you are confused about.

Comment: You don't mention even if you have tried to compile it. Have you? What do you understand from the compiler output result?

Comment: line 8 & 9 th... b=x; b=y;

Comment: compile error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion.

Comment: So, you're trying to store an int value (bigger) into a byte (smaller) box. Nothing related with the 'final' word. You'll find it useful to read the Java Tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Thank u community!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `final` keyword does mean "no further change", so you're correct there.  The issue here has to do with data "width".

An `int` can hold more data than a `byte` (i.e. it is "wider" than a `byte`). This means that when you do `b = x`, you're "narrowing" the width of the `int` to fit into the `byte`.  This only works if the compiler can *guarantee* that the `int` is small enough to fit into the `byte`, which requires the `int` to be <= 127, and to also be final (so that it cannot later be changed to be > 127).

In your code, both `x` and `y` are narrow enough to fit into a `byte`, but only `x` is final, so it's the only one the compiler allows to be directly assigned to a `byte` variable.

```
  final int x=127; final int y=100; // Made y final
  byte b;
  b=x; //Legal
  b=y; //Also legal
```

```
  final int x=200; final int y=100; // Made x too big
  byte b;
  b=x; //Illegal
  b=y; //Legal
```